# Windows 8 Devices - Shortcuts

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, shortcuts

Just bought a cheapo 15.5 Vaio with Windows 8 pre-loaded. I was able to pair it with a Philips wireless headset and it was great.

Thing is, each time I want to use this headset, I need to do this trackpad "*Swipe*" thing, click on *Settings*, then click on *Change PC Settings*, click on *Devices* from left menu bar and then on the right a list of deives including "PHilips SHB9100 - Offline" will appear. I can **finally** now click on it to do the bluetooth connection. That's 5 actions/clicks to re-connect a previously paired device. Very Microsoft!

Is there a shortcut to do the above more easily? In this scenario, all I need to do is (1) magic *Swipe*, (2) click on *Devices* and re-connect my device. That's only 2-3 actions.

At the moment, if I click on *Devices* after *Swiping*, the only thing listed is "Second Screen" and some other times "Microsoft XPS Document writer."

Thanks for any help you can bring.

Comment: What happens if you click the button on the headset? Don't that re-awaken the connection?

Answer (score 1):

I will play around with this, but I have found so far the simplest and speediest is to make a Windows shortcut to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,0
```

right click on the headset, then `Connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try. Download and install the [**Bluetooth Command Line Tools**](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/) and take a look at [**btpair**](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/btpair.html) in particular:

```
Bluetooth device pairing utility

btpair {-p[PIN] | -u} [-bBluetoothAddress | -nFriendlyName]

-p Pair your computer with remote device using specified PIN code.
   PIN code is optional (since version 1.2.0.56). If not provided '0000' is used.
-u  Unpair remote device.
-b  Bluetooth address of remote device in (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) format.
-n  Friendly name of remote device.
-h  Prints this help screen.
```

If it works, you can create a shortcut to btpair's executable with the appropriate arguments, or even a simple [batch file](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/bluetooth-sample-scripts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this free tool - [Shortcut Creator](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/shortcut-creator/) and it will create shortcut for you. I think portable devices is what you need, however I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly access Windows 8/8.1 bluetooth settings, create a shortcut pointing to:

> `explorer.exe localappdata%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPagePCSystemBluetooth.settingcontent-ms`

Note that the "en-US" portion will differ based on your locale.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread but I just wanted to thank Joel for pointing me in the right direction with this.  In my case, I wanted to be able to easily disable/enable Bluetooth (so I could switch my headphones between devices) so what I did was:

- on the desktop, create a shortcut to C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings[en-GB]\AAA_SettingsPagePCSystemBluetooth
- notice the [your username] which should be replaced, and the [en-GB], also notice that there is no '.settingcontent-ms' at the end of mine, I found that if I added that the shortcut didn't work (although viewing the properties of the shortcut after I created it does show the portion is automatically added)
- Having created the shortcut I then copied it to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
- Finally, I hit start to go into the modern UI and searched for the name of my shortcut, I was then able to right click and pin it to the start menu.

I hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making a desktop shortcut to access the Control Panel Bluetooth screen.

To do this go to the control panel applet  "bthprops.cpl" which should be in C:\Windows\System32
Now, rightclick on "bthprops.cpl" and select New>Shortcut.
Then you will be asked if the shortcut should be on desktop.
That fixed my issue of Bluetooth stopping and being hard to access for restart.
Once you have created a desktop shortcut, you can right click on the shortcut to run as Administrator, etc.

hope that helps